# Creating a wxImage using overloaded methods

Tags: python, wxpython, overloading

I am trying to create a wxImage that is just a solid red 16x16 square. To do this, I have done the following:

```
image = wx.EmptyImage(16, 16)
image.SetRGB(rect=wx.Rect(0,0,16,16), red=255, green=0, blue=0)
```

I am trying to use the second version of the `SetRGB` function found [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Image.html#Image.SetRGB).

However, I get the following:
`TypeError: Required argument 'x' (pos 2) not found`, which seems to indicate that it is trying to use the first version of the function.

I have also tried:

```
image.SetRGB(wx.Rect(0,0,16,16), 255, 0, 0)
```

and got the same error.

Is there a certain way to call this function that I am missing? I imagine I am just calling the function incorrectly, but I am not quite sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on which `wxPython` you are using:

```
img = wx.EmptyImage(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGH)
img.SetRGBRect(wx.Rect(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGH), 255, 0, 0)
bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
```

will work on wxPython 3.0/classic/MSW. You are referring in your link to wxPython 3.0/Phoenix, which is a different beast. There the above will crash the interpreter, while the line below will work.

```
img.SetRGB(wx.Rect(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGH), 255, 0, 0)
```

Something working on both platforms (and presumably what you want):

```
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGH, 255, 0, 0, 255)
img = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bmp)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful. I'm curious as to how you knew which functions would work on which platforms. Is there some sort of documentation highlighting the compatibility between the different versions? I have been using the documentation for both thinking they referred to the same version but some information was left out in each.

Comment: My steps to find out things like this: 1) Consult wxPython/Phoenix docs (because nice to read and will apply in 95 % of the cases 2) try it out and poke in the code (eclipse + PyDev and having ``virtualenv`` for the different wxPythons comes in handy) 3) Consult wxWidgets docs 4) search the internet

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's pretty much my process except for the part with `virtualenv`. I hadn't heard of that, but that sounds quite useful, I'll check it out.